# IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, language-agnostic, ioexception

I have some code and when it executes, it throws a `IOException`, saying that

> The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by
>   another process

What does this mean, and what can I do about it?

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/117902/831730) for how to find the other process that is using the file.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

### What is the cause?

The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to access a file, and it's not accessible because another process (or even the same process) is doing something with it (and it didn't allow any sharing).

### Debugging

It may be pretty easy to solve (or pretty hard to understand), depending on your specific scenario. Let's see some.

**Your process is the only one to access that file**
You're sure the *other* process is your own process. If you know you open that file in another part of your program, then first of all you have to check that you properly close the file handle after each use. Here is an example of code with this bug:

```
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileAccess.Read);
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
// Read data from this file, when I'm done I don't need it any more
File.Delete(path); // IOException: file is in use
```

Fortunately `FileStream` implements `IDisposable`, so it's easy to wrap all your code inside a `using` statement:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("myfile.txt", FileMode.Open)) {
    // Use stream
}

// Here stream is not accessible and it has been closed (also if
// an exception is thrown and stack unrolled
```

This pattern will also ensure that the file won't be left open in case of exceptions (it may be the reason the file is in use: something went wrong, and no one closed it; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641324/1207195) for an example).

If everything seems fine (you're sure you always close every file you open, even in case of exceptions) and you have multiple working threads, then you have two options: rework your code to serialize file access (not always doable and not always wanted) or apply a *retry pattern*. It's a pretty common pattern for I/O operations: you try to do something and in case of error you wait and try again (did you ask yourself why, for example, Windows Shell takes some time to inform you that a file is in use and cannot be deleted?). In C# it's pretty easy to implement (see also better examples about [disk I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10295561/1207195), [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014282/1207195) and [database access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24041546/1207195)).

```
private const int NumberOfRetries = 3;
private const int DelayOnRetry = 1000;

for (int i=1; i <= NumberOfRetries; ++i) {
    try {
        // Do stuff with file
        break; // When done we can break loop
    }
    catch (IOException e) when (i <= NumberOfRetries) {
        // You may check error code to filter some exceptions, not every error
        // can be recovered.
        Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
    }
}
```

Please note a common error we see very often on StackOverflow:

```
var stream = File.Open(path, FileOpen.Read);
var content = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

In this case `ReadAllText()` will fail because the file is in use (`File.Open()` in the line before). To open the file beforehand is not only unnecessary but also wrong. The same applies to all `File` functions that don't return a *handle* to the file you're working with: `File.ReadAllText()`, `File.WriteAllText()`, `File.ReadAllLines()`, `File.WriteAllLines()` and others  (like `File.AppendAllXyz()` functions) will all open and close the file by themselves.

**Your process is not the only one to access that file**
If your process is not the only one to access that file, then interaction can be harder. A *retry pattern* will help (if the file shouldn't be open by anyone else but it is, then you need a utility like Process Explorer to check *who* is doing *what*).

### Ways to avoid

When applicable, always use *using* statements to open files. As said in previous paragraph, it'll actively help you to avoid many common errors (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3803929/1207195) for an example on **how not to use it**).

If possible, try to decide who owns access to a specific file and centralize access through a few well-known methods. If, for example, you have a data file where your program reads and writes, then you should box all I/O code inside a single class. It'll make debug easier (because you can always put a breakpoint there and see who is doing what) and also it'll be a synchronization point (if required) for multiple access.

Don't forget I/O operations can always fail, a common example is this:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
    File.Delete(path);
```

If *someone* deletes the file after `File.Exists()` but before `File.Delete()`, then it'll throw an `IOException` in a place where you may wrongly feel safe.

Whenever it's possible, apply a *retry pattern*, and if you're using `FileSystemWatcher`, consider postponing action (because you'll get notified, but an application may still be working exclusively with that file).

**Advanced scenarios**
It's not always so easy, so you may need to share access with someone else. If, for example, you're reading from the beginning and writing to the end, you have at least two options.

1) share the same `FileStream` with proper synchronization functions (because **it is not thread-safe**). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3457725/1207195) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8893449/1207195) posts for an example.

2) use `FileShare` enumeration to instruct OS to allow other processes (or other parts of your own process) to access same file concurrently.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
}
```

In this example I showed how to open a file for writing and share for reading; please note that when reading and writing overlaps, it results in undefined or invalid data. It's a situation that must be handled when reading. Also note that this doesn't make access to the `stream` thread-safe, so this object can't be shared with multiple threads unless access is synchronized somehow (see previous links). Other sharing options are available, and they open up more complex scenarios. Please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

In general *N* processes can read from same file all together but only one should write, in a controlled scenario you may even enable concurrent writings but this can't be generalized in few text paragraphs inside this answer.

Is it possible to **unlock** a file used by another process? It's not always safe and not so easy but yes, [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35058113/1207195).

Comment: My code uses `Directory.SetCreationTimeUTC()` but it fails when File Explorer is open, claiming the directory is being accessed by another process. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'd say that you need to wait until folder has been closed, if it's not a few seconds thing then everything will quickly become complex (keep a background queue with pending operations? File system watcher? Polling?) You may want to post a question with more details for an ad-hoc answer

Comment: A good tip is to be careful with the new syntax of `using` where you don't need to use `{}`. Because I was doing things like `using var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);` I was trying to read that file again in another method and forgot that the using wasn't closed

Comment: I have up voted this answer as retry with delay did work for me. I wrote a single threaded program to download media files from iphone to a alternate ssd on my pc and update Creation/LastModified/LastAccess timestamps with each successful download. The IO error occurs randomly as the file proccessed count gets higher. It should not have happened, but it did, my only resolution is to use retry with delay.

Answer (score 54):

Using **FileShare** fixed my issue of opening file even if it is opened by another process.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
}
```

Answer (score 17):

**Problem**

one is tying to open file `System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode)` with this method and want a shared access on file but

if u read documentation of **System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode)** it is explicitly saying its does not *allow sharing*

[image]

**Solution**

use you have to use other override with [FileShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netcore-3.1)
[image]

```
using FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

with  `FileShare.Read`

Comment: This solution was the best for me.  I originally had my code as above without FileShare.Read which was causing exceptions.  Adding FileShare.Read solved the problem straight away.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data, documentation or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that the text is readable without having to re-type everything, and your post can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Just closing all the stream worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Had an issue while uploading an image and couldn't delete it and found a solution. gl hf

```
//C# .NET
var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);

image.Dispose(); // this removes all resources

//later...

File.Delete(filePath); //now works
```

Comment: If you are deleting a file, you need to dispose the image object first.

Comment: Nice, I looked for this solution. I had also a problem with Image.FromFile function.

Comment: @thescion :) np

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me and solved my exact problem.  I wanted to process a folder of Tiff files, convert them to byte[] streams and send to a service, and then move the folder of Tiff files to a "Processed" archive folder.  The Image.FromFile places a lock on the Tiff file, and does not release it timely, so when I went to move the Tiff files and containing folder, I would get the "being used by another process" error, as the locks were still in place.  Doing the .Release right after getting the bytes of the Tiff file totally fixed this locked file problem.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers in this thread have pointed out, to resolve this error you need to carefully inspect the code, to understand where the file is getting locked.

In my case, I was sending out the file as an email attachment before performing the move operation.

So the file got locked for couple of seconds until SMTP client finished sending the email.

The solution I adopted was to **move the file first, and then send the email.** This solved the problem for me.

Another possible solution, as pointed out earlier by Hudson, would've been to dispose the object after use.

```
public static SendEmail()
{
           MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();
           //setup other email stuff

            if (File.Exists(attachmentPath))
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                attachment.Dispose(); //disposing the Attachment object
            }
}
```

Comment: If a file is in use `File.Move()` won't work & gives the same error. If just adding a file to an e-mail I don't think it errors when in use during the `Attachments.Add()` operation because this is just a copy operation. If it did for some reason you could copy it to a Temp directory, attach the copy, & delete the copied file afterwards. But I don't think, if the OP wants to modify a file & use that, that this kind of solution (which you didn't show the code of, only the attaching portion) would work. `.Dispose()` is always a good idea, but not relevant here unless file is opened in a prior op.

Comment: I had the similar type of scenario. I was not able to move file after sending the email.
In my case:

mailMessageObj.Attachments.Dispose() after sending the emails worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I was doing File.Move to a file path without a file name, need to specify the full path in the destination.

Comment: And not just without a filename either. An illegal (destination) filename - in my case "...\file." - will give this same stupid error and point you in the wrong direction for half a day!

Answer (score 4):

The error indicates another process is trying to access the file.  Maybe you or someone else has it open while you are attempting to write to it.  "Read" or "Copy" usually doesn't cause this, but writing to it or calling delete on it would.

There are some basic things to avoid this, as other answers have mentioned:

1. In `FileStream` operations, place it in a `using` block with a `FileShare.ReadWrite` mode of access.

   For example:

   ```
   using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   {
   }
   ```

   Note that `FileAccess.ReadWrite` is not possible if you use `FileMode.Append`.
2. I ran across this issue when I was using an input stream to do a `File.SaveAs` when the file was in use.  In my case I found, I didn't actually need to save it back to the file system at all, so I ended up just removing that, but I probably could've tried creating a FileStream in a `using` statement with `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, much like the code above.
3. Saving your data as a different file and going back to delete the old one when it is found to be no longer in use, then renaming the one that saved successfully to the name of the original one is an option.  How you test for the file being in use is accomplished through the

   ```
   List<Process> lstProcs = ProcessHandler.WhoIsLocking(file);
   ```

   line in my code below, and could be done in a Windows service, on a loop, if you have a particular file you want to watch and delete regularly when you want to replace it.  If you don't always have the same file, a text file or database table could be updated that the service always checks for file names, and then performs that check for processes & subsequently performs the process kills and deletion on it, as I describe in the next option.  Note that you'll need an account user name and password that has Admin privileges on the given computer, of course, to perform the deletion and ending of processes.
4. When you don't know if a file will be in use when you are trying to save it, you can close all processes that could be using it, like Word, if it's a Word document, ahead of the save.

   If it is local, you can do this:

   ```
   ProcessHandler.localProcessKill("winword.exe");
   ```

   If it is remote, you can do this:

   ```
   ProcessHandler.remoteProcessKill(computerName, txtUserName, txtPassword, "winword.exe");
   ```

   where `txtUserName` is in the form of `DOMAIN\user`.
5. Let's say you don't know the process name that is locking the file. Then, you can do this:

   ```
   List<Process> lstProcs = new List<Process>();
   lstProcs = ProcessHandler.WhoIsLocking(file);

   foreach (Process p in lstProcs)
   {
       if (p.MachineName == ".")
           ProcessHandler.localProcessKill(p.ProcessName);
       else
           ProcessHandler.remoteProcessKill(p.MachineName, txtUserName, txtPassword, p.ProcessName);
   }
   ```

   Note that `file` must be the UNC path:  `\\computer\share\yourdoc.docx` in order for the `Process` to figure out what computer it's on and `p.MachineName` to be valid.

   Below is the class these functions use, which requires adding a reference to `System.Management`. The code was [originally written by Eric J.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623311):

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Management;

   namespace MyProject
   {
       public static class ProcessHandler
       {
           [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
           struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
           {
               public int dwProcessId;
               public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
           }

           const int RmRebootReasonNone = 0;
           const int CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
           const int CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

           enum RM_APP_TYPE
           {
               RmUnknownApp = 0,
               RmMainWindow = 1,
               RmOtherWindow = 2,
               RmService = 3,
               RmExplorer = 4,
               RmConsole = 5,
               RmCritical = 1000
           }

           [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
           struct RM_PROCESS_INFO
           {
               public RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS Process;

               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME + 1)]
               public string strAppName;

               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME + 1)]
               public string strServiceShortName;

               public RM_APP_TYPE ApplicationType;
               public uint AppStatus;
               public uint TSSessionId;
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
               public bool bRestartable;
           }

           [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
           static extern int RmRegisterResources(uint pSessionHandle,
                                               UInt32 nFiles,
                                               string[] rgsFilenames,
                                               UInt32 nApplications,
                                               [In] RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS[] rgApplications,
                                               UInt32 nServices,
                                               string[] rgsServiceNames);

           [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
           static extern int RmStartSession(out uint pSessionHandle, int dwSessionFlags, string strSessionKey);

           [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
           static extern int RmEndSession(uint pSessionHandle);

           [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
           static extern int RmGetList(uint dwSessionHandle,
                                       out uint pnProcInfoNeeded,
                                       ref uint pnProcInfo,
                                       [In, Out] RM_PROCESS_INFO[] rgAffectedApps,
                                       ref uint lpdwRebootReasons);

           /// <summary>
           /// Find out what process(es) have a lock on the specified file.
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="path">Path of the file.</param>
           /// <returns>Processes locking the file</returns>
           /// <remarks>See also:
           /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373661(v=vs.85).aspx
           /// http://wyupdate.googlecode.com/svn-history/r401/trunk/frmFilesInUse.cs (no copyright in code at time of viewing)
           /// 
           /// </remarks>
           static public List<Process> WhoIsLocking(string path)
           {
               uint handle;
               string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
               List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();

               int res = RmStartSession(out handle, 0, key);
               if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not begin restart session.  Unable to determine file locker.");

               try
               {
                   const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
                   uint pnProcInfoNeeded = 0,
                       pnProcInfo = 0,
                       lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone;

                   string[] resources = new string[] { path }; // Just checking on one resource.

                   res = RmRegisterResources(handle, (uint)resources.Length, resources, 0, null, 0, null);

                   if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not register resource.");

                   //Note: there's a race condition here -- the first call to RmGetList() returns
                   //      the total number of process. However, when we call RmGetList() again to get
                   //      the actual processes this number may have increased.
                   res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, null, ref lpdwRebootReasons);

                   if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                   {
                       // Create an array to store the process results
                       RM_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfo = new RM_PROCESS_INFO[pnProcInfoNeeded];
                       pnProcInfo = pnProcInfoNeeded;

                       // Get the list
                       res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, processInfo, ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                       if (res == 0)
                       {
                           processes = new List<Process>((int)pnProcInfo);

                           // Enumerate all of the results and add them to the 
                           // list to be returned
                           for (int i = 0; i < pnProcInfo; i++)
                           {
                               try
                               {
                                   processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(processInfo[i].Process.dwProcessId));
                               }
                               // catch the error -- in case the process is no longer running
                               catch (ArgumentException) { }
                           }
                       }
                       else throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource.");
                   }
                   else if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource. Failed to get size of result.");
               }
               finally
               {
                   RmEndSession(handle);
               }

               return processes;
           }

           public static void remoteProcessKill(string computerName, string userName, string pword, string processName)
           {
               var connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
               connectoptions.Username = userName;
               connectoptions.Password = pword;

               ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + computerName + @"\root\cimv2", connectoptions);

               // WMI query
               var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_process where name = '" + processName + "'");

               using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
               {
                   foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get()) 
                   {
                       process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
                       process.Dispose();
                   }
               }            
           }

           public static void localProcessKill(string processName)
           {
               foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
               {
                   p.Kill();
               }
           }

           [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
           public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

           public const int MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x4;

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and it was solved by following the code below

```
var _path=MyFile.FileName;
using (var stream = new FileStream
    (_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
  { 
    // Your Code! ;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a very specific situation where I was getting an *"IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path'"* on the line

```cs
File.Delete(fileName);
```

Inside an NUnit test that looked like:

```cs
Assert.Throws<IOException>(() =>
{
    using (var sr = File.OpenText(fileName) {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
});
File.Delete(fileName);
```

It turns out NUnit 3 uses something they call "isolated context" for exception assertions. This probably runs on a separate thread.

My fix was to put the `File.Delete` *in* the same context.

```cs
Assert.Throws<IOException>(() =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var sr = File.OpenText(fileName) {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
        throw;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the following scenario that was causing the same error:

- Upload files to the server
- Then get rid of the old files after they have been uploaded

Most files were small in size, however, a few were large, and so attempting to delete those resulted in the *cannot access file* error.

It was not easy to find, however, the solution was as simple as [Waiting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) "for the task to complete execution":

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
   var tskResult = wc.UploadFileTaskAsync(_address, _fileName);
   tskResult.Wait(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was solved by Opening the file for **Shared writing/reading**. Following are the sample codes for shared reading and writing:-
**Stream Writer**

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\test.txt", 
FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.WriteLine("any thing which you want to write");
}
```

**Stream Reader**

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader rr=new StreamReader(fs))
{
    rr.ReadLine())
}
```

Answer (score -3):

My below code solve this issue, but i suggest
First of all you need to understand what causing this issue and try the solution which you can find by changing code

I can give another way to solve this issue but better solution is to check your coding structure and try to analyse what makes this happen,if you do not find any solution then you can go with this code below

```
try{
Start:
///Put your file access code here


}catch (Exception ex)
 {
//by anyway you need to handle this error with below code
   if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The process cannot access the file"))
    {
         //Wait for 5 seconds to free that file and then start execution again
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
         goto Start;
    }
 }
```

Comment: A few problems with this code:1) if you need to call `GC.*()` then you probably have other issues with your code. 2) Message is localized and _fragile_, use the HRESULT instead. 3) You may want to sleep with `Task.Delay()` (and ten seconds is somehow excessive in manyt cases). 4) You do not have an exit condition: this code could hang forver. 5) You definitely do not need `goto` here. 6) To catch `Exception` is usually a bad idea, in this case also because... 6) If anything else happen then you're swallowing the error.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti my first comment said do not use this code try to find other solution this will be last option and   anyhow if this error happens code get stopped but if you are handling this error system will wait to free the file and after that it will start working and i do not face other issues with GC.* while using this code.i already have working system with this code so i posted may be helpful for someone.

Comment: I'd say to do not use this code _ever_ (because of the points I mentioned above) and I'd not consider this _working_ in a prod system but that's just my POV. Feel free to disagree!

Comment: 1)I used windows service where i consumed this and i used GC.* upto this i do not face any issue with this2)yeah HRESULT can be better option in terms of coding standard3)Depend on the situation you can give time i just edited it to 5 seconds 4)anyhow it is better to system wait for sometime to free resource instead of stop the system with error 5)yes i am agree with you exception handling is not always good idea but if your code snippet is small and you know that here i can handle exception then this solution is an option for you.

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/when-to-call-gc-collect. The ONLY (and I stress ONLY) case I needed to use `GC.Collect()` has been when dealing with some COM objects.

Comment: 4) no, definitely not. It can hang forever and it might be your own program to keep it open then it won't EVER exit. 5) Is it an option to handle `StackOverflowException` or `OutOfMemoryException` in this way (swalling and repeating)? After those errors are you sure that your program data is still correct? No, it's VERY hard to write code that can handle and resume an out of memory condition. VERY hard, and definitely not swallowing and ignoring the error.

Comment: Yeah thats why i said check your code first maybe you opened streamreader and haven't close it or you miss to dispose object but there are the cases where your files are used by external resources as well who are using same file to do some operation or some external programs who are using these files in that situation your system can wait for sometime to make other programs to end there task and resume after file becomes free.

Comment: Sorry but I still consider this answer completely _wrong_ even after you removed the GC part. You're basically suggesting to do a `while (true)` loop using `goto`, catching all exceptions and then discriminate using the error message. Nothing to understand better, just suboptimal (IMHO) even for a throw-away script.