# File is being used by another process in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I am trying to delete a file in C#, however I am receiving a message that the file is used from another process. What I want to do is to check if the files exists and close it. I am using the following function in order to check if the file is open:

```
public static bool IsFileInUse(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            throw new ArgumentException("'path' cannot be null or empty.", "path");

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

and I am trying when the file is in use to close it:

```
bool checking = IsFileInUse(file );
File.Create(file ).Close();
if (File.Exists(file))
{
       File.Delete(file );
}
```

I got issues in File.Create line, I am receiving the message:

> File is being used by another process.

**EDIT:** I am trying to use lock approach in order to delete the file. Am I suppose to delete the file inside a lock statement? How Can I use properly the lock statement?

Comment: You can not close file that is opened by some other process by any straight forward method.

Comment: Therefore I should kill the process in order to close the file, right?

Comment: Is that your application? If yes then you can send message to release it or use inter-process lock

Comment: What is the other process that uses it? Is it your app itself?

Comment: You do not handle the return value of IsFileInUse, before calling File.Create.

Comment: ... well why don't you just try to delete it and wrap this into a `try ... catch`? I don't think your `IsFileInUse` will work anyway (you can use a file without blocking read access)

Comment: The other process is a thread that uses the file.

Comment: You need to use lock between threads to ensure the file handle is released by thread before other takes it for delete.

Comment: Can you please give me some detail on the lock procedure?

Comment: You can find a lot of article on locking, multi-threading, this is what msdn tell about lock, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: I am not sure that I catch the lock procedure. I have to abort thread inside a lock statement?

Comment: thread.Abort does not really close the thread, right?

Comment: I have got to add delete inside a lock statement, right?

Comment: @JoseRamon it has nothing to do with thread synchronization. See also [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you suppose that a reading operation will fail if file is in use while a writing operation will not? `File.Create()` will fail exactly as new `FileStream()` failed before...

See also  [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being).

Note that your check will fail if the other process didn't open that file exclusively (check `FileShare` enumeration): file may be open for shared reading, writing and sometimes even for deleting (for example you may be able to read concurrently but not writing however the other process may let you *delete* that file...).

To close an open file can be really disruptive for the other process, it may crash, nicely handle the problem or...anything else (silently ignore that error and produce random output, open file again and so on...) Is it possible to do it in C#? Yes with some P/Invoke...

1) Let's find the handle for the file you want to *unlock*. Use `NtQuerySystemInformation()` and enumerate all handles until you find the one that refers to that file.

2) Duplicate that handle to be valid in your own process using `DuplicateHandle()`.

3) Close just create handle specifying `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE`, it will close both your handle and the original one (of course if your process has enough permissions).

4) Check if file is really closed calling `NtQuerySystemInformation()` again, if not then you may need to directly close its parent process.

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to *check* if the file exists, just try do *delete* it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

Try and check the exception

```
  try {
    File.Delete(file);
  }
  catch (IOException) {
    // File in use and can't be deleted; no permission etc.
  }
```

Comment: My file is being used by another process, so I need to close that process (thread) in order to delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you don't do anything with the IsFileInUse result.

This `File.Create(file ).Close();` will also not close a file that is opened by another process. You need to close the process that has the file open, and if it is your own app, close the file handle before trying to delete the file.

```
bool checking = IsFileInUse(file );
File.Create(file ).Close();
if (!checking) 
{
     if (File.Exists(file))
     {
            File.Delete(file );
     }
}
```

Comment: My file is being used by another process, so I need to close that process (thread) in order to delete the file.

Comment: @JoseRamon you can do it (close that process, [after you found it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35058113/1207195)) but it's something to do carefully.

Comment: Is this the way to close a thread https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx ?