# C#: Cant access file after creating

Tags: c#, file, directory, system.io.file

i'm trying to create a json file if it doesn't exist, and then write all lines to it. The creation of the file works, but the problem i have is that File.WriteAllLines says "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Here's my code:

```
public void generateFolderFiles(string folderToSearch, string fileToEdit) {
        string[] filesToSearch = Directory.GetFiles(folderToSearch);
        string completeJson = "";
        for(int i=0;i<filesToSearch.Length;i++) {
            try {
                File.Delete(fileToEdit);
                File.Create(fileToEdit);
            } catch(Exception e){}
            string[] fsLines = File.ReadAllLines(filesToSearch[i]);
            string fsText = string.Join("", fsLines);
            fsText=fsText.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            completeJson+=fsText;
        }
        completeJson="["+completeJson+"]";
        string[] lnes = new string[1]{completeJson};
        File.WriteAllLines(fileToEdit, lnes);
    }
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being

Comment: `for` loop seems a little weird to me; let's say you have 10 files in `folderToSearch`; then you delete and create the same `fileToEdit` file 10 times as that string does not change in the code you provided.

Comment: empty `catch` blocks don't help you or anyone else.

Comment: @mcy Oh yes, thanks, i need to take it out of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

`File.Create()` returns a `FileStream` which you can use to do the file IO. While `FileStream` is open (and in your case it remains open for who knows how long because you do not call neither `Close()`, nor `Dispose()` on it), it does not not allow anybody else to access it (in reality, things are a bit more complex), which is why your `WriteAllLines()` call fails.