# System.IO.IOException:The process cannot access the file Filename.config (it is being used by same process)

Tags: .net, file-io, io, jit, ioexception

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being) post, in my code everything seems to be proper! 
I'm using [Dockpanel](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) suite to save & load layout. problem here is in saving layout. while debugging from visual studio, when i close winform(save layout) it takes long time(10 seconds) then VS stops debugging session. 
if i run exe directly, after closing application(need to click on 'x' button twice!) i receive the following error

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test\Release\Layout.config' because it is being used by another
>   process. 
>    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath) 
>    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost) 
>    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) 
>    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) 
>    at
>   InsightRealityv2.Main.Main_FormClosing(Object sender,
>   FormClosingEventArgs e) in c:\users\Admin\documents\visual studio
>   2015\projects\test\insight reality v2\main.h:line 573
>   .
>   .
>   .

now, According to the error message "Layout.config" is still open. but i'm closing FileStream. below is my code (function called when form loads)

```
Void load_layout()
{   
    System::String^ path = Path::Combine(Path::GetDirectoryName(Application::ExecutablePath), "Layout.config");
    if (File::Exists(path)) 
    {
        FileStream ^fs1 = gcnew FileStream(path, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read);
        Stream ^s1 = fs1;
        DeserializeDockContent ^m_deserializeDockContent = gcnew DeserializeDockContent(this, &Main::GetContentFromPersistString);
        dockPanel1->LoadFromXml(path, m_deserializeDockContent);
        fs1->Close();
        s1->Close();
    }
}
```

below code is called when form closing event triggers

```
Void Save_Layout()
{
   System::String^ path = Path::Combine(Path::GetDirectoryName(Application::ExecutablePath), "Layout.config");
   FileStream ^fs = gcnew FileStream(path, FileMode::Create);
   Stream ^s = fs;
   dockPanel1->SaveAsXml(s, System::Text::Encoding::Unicode, false);
   fs->Close();
   s->Close();  
}
```

both the function is been called only once from same UI thread.

Comment: This code is not exception-safe.  With pretty decent odds that you use try/catch-em-all in the caller so you can't see that it failed to load the file, threw an exception and thus failed to close the file.  Use *stack semantics* or the `finally` keyword.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks for your comment. i wrapped load_layout block with try catch. it didn't help. its closing FileStream properly itself!

Comment: Well, I guessed you used try/catch in the caller.  The problem is that it **doesn't** close the FileStream.  The exception bypasses your fs->Close() call.  Google "stack semantics", take the first hit.