# Read a file immediately after uploading it in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, file-read

I just uploaded a file to the wwwroot/files folder of my project.  What I intend to do is read the file immediately after uploading it.
The code I have used to upload the file works fine but the one for reading the file throws this Exception:
 *An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'campuses.sql' because it is being used by another process.* Campuses.sql is the file I'm trying to upload and read.
Below is my code for uploading and reading the file.

```
 public IActionResult Institution(IFormFile InstitutionFile)
    {
        if(InstitutionFile != null)
        {
            var fileName = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath + "/files/", Path.GetFileName(InstitutionFile.FileName));
            InstitutionFile.CopyTo(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));

       //Everything runs fine till here

            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.  
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();

            System.Console.ReadLine();



        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Institutions");

    }
```

So:
1. I suspect it is the upload process which is still using the file. How can I stop the process using the file so that I can read it?

2. Is there another way that can help me go round this?

I intend to read data from an .csv file and insert the records into a database in the long run.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using a `FileStream` and not disposing it (actually you're not disposing any of your *streams*). You should always make sure you dispose instances that implement `IDisposable` in order to free up unmanaged resources. Checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741192/967736)

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped a lot. @IPValverde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from `InstitutionFile` instead of physical file.

Also put `FileStream` into `using` block so it will release the file.

```
var fileName = Path.Combine("" + "/files/", Path.GetFileName(InstitutionFile.FileName));
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
      InstitutionFile.CopyTo(fileStream);

var st = new MemoryStream();
InstitutionFile.CopyTo(st);
var content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(st.ToArray());
```

Comment: It might work but the problem is the file will still not be available to other processes which might want to use it

Comment: @CalebRotich after `FileStream` will finish the writing and goes out of scope (at the end of action) it will release the file.

Comment: Putting FileStream into Using block worked, thanks. Everything else remained constant though.