# XML Writer not working in C# ( with-in a .NET MVC web application )

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I am trying to read and write to an XML file within a .NET MVC web application. The XML reader ( GetScoresXMLReader() ) is working - it is able to output to a web page. But the XML writer ( AddScoresXMLWriter ) is not working for the form page. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong please? Below is the User class which defines the XML methods and the controller class ( for the AddACustomer view ) from which I am calling the XML methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication10.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("User"), XmlType("User")]
    public class Users
    {

        // Get the current directory.
        static string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        static String binPath = path + "\\binary\\data.bin";
        static String xmlPath = path + "\\Properties\\Users.xml";


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must specifiy a first name")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must specifiy a last name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Must specifiy a role")]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Role { get; set; }


        //Parameter Less constructor needed for XML Serialization Only!!!
        public Users() { }


        //CONSTRUCTOR 
        public Users( String fname, String lname, String date)
        {
            FirstName = fname;
            LastName = lname;
            Role = date;
        }

        public String DisplayUser()
        {
            return ("First Name: " + FirstName + ", Last Name:" + LastName + ", Role: " + Role + "/n");
        }


        public class XMLReader
        {


            public static List<Users> AddScoresXMLWriter(Users userSet)
                {
                    List<Users> userList = GetScoresXMLReader();

                    userList.Add(userSet);
                    var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Users>));
                    var xmlFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(xmlPath);
                    writer.Serialize(xmlFile, userList);
                    xmlFile.Close();

                return userList;
                }

            public static List<Users> GetScoresXMLReader()
            {
                List<Users> eventList = new List<Users>();
                try
                {
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Users>));
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlPath);
                    eventList = (List<Users>)reader.Deserialize(file);
                    file.Close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fex)
                {
                    Debug.Write(fex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Write(ex.Message);
                }
                return eventList;
            }


            //FOR LIST ALL CUSTOMERS PAGE

            public List<Users> OutPutListOfAllUsers()
            {  
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();//Using dataset to read xml file  
                ds.ReadXml(xmlPath);
                var results = new List<Users>();
                results = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            select new Users
                            {
                                FirstName = rows[0].ToString(), //Convert row to int  
                                LastName = rows[1].ToString(),
                                Role = rows[2].ToString(),
                            }).ToList();
                return results;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And here is the controller from which the XML writer is called.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplication10.Models;
using static WebApplication10.Models.Users;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult ViewAllUsers()
        {
            XMLReader readXML = new XMLReader();
            var data = readXML.OutPutListOfAllUsers();
            return View(data.ToList());
        }

        public IActionResult AboutMe()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddACustomer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddACustomer(Users user)
        {
            // do validation 
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //ADD FORM INPUT TO XML FILE
                XMLReader.AddScoresXMLWriter(user);
                return View(user);
            }
            // save user

            //redirect

            return Redirect("/");
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

If I load ViewAllCustomers page I can see the entries that I have manually added to the XML but When I fill out all required fields of form (on AddACustomer page) it submits but the XML is not modified. If I try to submit the form incompletely then I get an error that XML file is in use.

[image: When loading page from menu or when redirected from AddACustomer page after form submission - no errors but XML is not appended with form submission]

If form submit button is clicked but form is incomplete then error is generated that XML is in use and cannot be written to.

[image]

Comment: Please could you tell us what "not working for the form page" means. Is incorrect data written, is no data written, does the computer crash, or something else?

Comment: The form submits but the XML is not appended with form information. I've updated the post with pictures. I hope it is clearer.  The XML read method is working but the XML write function is not working.

Comment: If this is for a multi-user application then you should use a multi-user-capable database. Apart from that, where the code has `var xmlFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(xmlPath);` it ought to be using the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to make sure that unmanaged resources are cleaned up properly.

Comment: Andrew - you are correct! I had to add the 'using' statement to the XML reader method, which opens the XML before returning a list of user objects to be passed to the XML writer. Thank you very much! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being)