# How can I delete the old one while uploading a new image with c #

Tags: c#, .net, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to delete old image when uploading new one with c# but I get
`the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` error

```
public void DeleteExistImage(string imageName)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/" + imageName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `File.Delete(path)` outside the `using` block. Remove `stream.Dispose()`: that's what the `using` block is for. Assuming the `FileStream` is used to open a stream to send the image. Otherwise, just `File.Delete(path)` after you have closed the Stream that opened the Image. -- I hope you're not trying to create a new Stream to close the original Stream that has been opened somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to delete the file and then create a new file

```
string path = @"c:\mytext.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

Also, look into the thread if it solves your issue
[IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being)

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a link. Look of you can find any answer