# UWP app is getting crashed with an error - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, uwp, crash

My UWP application is getting crashed with some unspecified errors

|FATAL|2|Application|The application crashed: Unspecified error

App_UnhandledException() EX = The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The file is in use. Please close the file before continuing.

Comment: Please share the code how do you access the file.

Comment: Are you using System.IO? Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741192/13123352) might be helpful. If not, give us some more information please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running VS as administrator? Maybe you should have written part of the program here.