# Creating File, then writing it returns IOException "File is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, io

Here, I create 2 new files, and when I try to `File.WriteAllLines()`, it returns an IOException saying that the file is already being used by another process:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempShiftPath);
File.Create(tempShiftPath + "Info.shift");
File.Create(tempShiftPath + "Legs.shift");

string[] infoContents =
{
    Convert.ToString(shift.TimeFrame.Start) + ";" + Convert.ToString(shift.TimeFrame.End),
    shift.Description
};
File.WriteAllLines(tempShiftPath + "Info.shift", infoContents); // Error occures here
return shift;
```

#### Things I have tried

I have already read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being), and I am sure that the "other process" is my process.

I have also added a few seconds of sleep between the creat and the write methods, but that obviously didn't work.

Honestly, I have no idea what is wrong, because it worked some time ago, but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.Create` opens a stream to the file. This stream needs to closed, or you will get the error you describe.
However, `File.WriteAllLines` creates the file on its own, so there is no need for the `File.Create` statement.
This should work just fine:

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempShiftPath);
string[] infoContents =
{
    Convert.ToString(shift.TimeFrame.Start) + ";" + Convert.ToString(shift.TimeFrame.End),
    shift.Description
};
File.WriteAllLines(tempShiftPath + "Info.shift", infoContents); // No error occurs here
return shift;
```

`File.Create` is meant to be used something like this:

```cs
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    fs.Write(byteArray, 0, length);
}
```