Upload multiple images, display a list with filename and new filename, and handle renaming on both source and destination directories(Laravel + AJAX)?
I’m working on a Laravel project where I need to implement a multiple image upload feature with the following requirements:

Shared Directories:

The source folder and destination folder are network-shared paths.
After uploading the files to the destination folder with the new names, the files should be renamed in the source folder as well.
My Problem:
However, I’m struggling with:

Renaming the files in both the source directories.
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Image Upload with Rename</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Upload and Rename Images</h2>
  <input type="file" id="images" multiple>

  <table id="imageTable" border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Preview</th>
              <th>Original Filename</th>
              <th>New Filename</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="uploadImages">Upload</button>

  <!-- Modal for Preview -->
  <div id="previewModal" style="display: none;">
      <span id="closeModal" style="cursor: pointer;">Close</span>
      <img id="previewImage" src="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
  </div>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          // Handle image selection
          $('#images').change(function(event) {
              let files = event.target.files;
              let tableBody = $('#imageTable tbody');
              tableBody.empty();  // Clear previous data

              $.each(files, function(index, file) {
                  let fileRow = `<tr>
                      <td><img src="${URL.createObjectURL(file)}" width="100" height="100"></td>
                      <td>${file.name}</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="newFilename[]" class="newFilename"></td>
                      <td><button class="deleteRow">Delete</button></td>
                  </tr>`;
                  tableBody.append(fileRow);
              });
          });

          // Handle double click to preview image
          $(document).on('dblclick', '#imageTable tbody tr', function() {
              let imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
              $('#previewImage').attr('src', imgSrc);
              $('#previewModal').show();
          });

          // Close the image preview modal
          $('#closeModal').click(function() {
              $('#previewModal').hide();
          });

          // Handle delete row
          $(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
              $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          });

          // Upload images
          $('#uploadImages').click(function() {
              let formData = new FormData();
              let files = $('#images')[0].files;

              // Loop through each file and add to FormData
              $('#imageTable tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
                  let newFilename = $(row).find('.newFilename').val();
                  if (newFilename === '') {
                      // Remove row if new filename is empty
                      $(row).remove();
                  } else {
                      formData.append('images[]', files[index]);
                      formData.append('newFilenames[]', newFilename);
                  }
              });

              // AJAX to upload images and rename
              $.ajax({
                  url: '/upload-images',
                  method: 'POST',
                  data: formData,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  success: function(response) {
                      alert('Images uploaded successfully!');
                  },
                  error: function(err) {
                      alert('Error uploading images.');
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>

  </body>



Route code:
Route::post('/upload-images', 'ImageController@uploadImages');

Controller code:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImages(Request $request)
    {
        $images = $request->file('images');
        $newFilenames = $request->input('newFilenames');
        
        $sourcePath = '\\\\172.20.1.201\\source\\';
        $destinationPath = '\\\\172.20.1.201\\destination\\';

        foreach ($images as $index => $image) {
            $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $newName = $newFilenames[$index] . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // Save to destination directory
            $destinationFullPath = $destinationPath . $newName;
            Storage::disk('network')->putFileAs($destinationPath, $image, $newName);

            // Rename file in source folder
            $sourceFullPath = $sourcePath . $originalName;
            $newSourcePath = $sourcePath . $newName;
            
            if (file_exists($sourceFullPath)) {
                rename($sourceFullPath, $newSourcePath);
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Images uploaded and renamed successfully']);
    }
}

I have tried above code for delete that time also same error message:
// Move the file to destination and remove from the source folder
if ($file->move($destinationPath, $newName)) {
    if (File::exists($source)) {
        File::delete($source);  // Removing the file from the source directory
    }
}

Error Message:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (code: 32)

We are using file upload Html form some time we will select file from any random folder also that time we will not take care of rename file into source folder.

"Struggling" in what way, exactly? What have you tried? What problem did you have? Please be specific about the problem, otherwise it makes it more difficult to help you accurately.

Also, if the problem relates to the handling of file renaming, and network storage issues, then this sounds like a server-side thing only. So presumably your jQuery and HTML code is not relevant...please make sure you only post a [mre] of the specific problem, showing the code which you can't get to work, and remove any distracting clutter from your post. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your question, of course. A clearer, more focused question will be a lot easier to answer. Thankyou.

The source folder and destination folder...what do you mean? Surely, from the PHP application's point of view, the source of the images is the file upload box in the HTML form? If the images are already stored on a network folder which the server has access to, then why would the user need to select and upload them again?

Source and Destination folder means I am having fix folder from where I am going to pic k file and I want to rename source folder file name after it got uploaded into destination folder.

actually problem is when I am trying to delete file or rename I am not able to but when In the same folder not used file I am trying to rename or delete it;s happening

I am having fix folder from where I am going to pic k file...then why make the user upload the file? What a waste of effort and bandwidth. Just let them choose the file from a list, and the server can then access it directly over the network

@ADyson I am getting error  "message": "rename(\\...\CivilIdTest\fivil.jpg,\\...\CivilIdTest\ArchivedFiles\fivil.jpg): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (code: 32)",

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process "...ok. Sounds like somebody else already has the file open then. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being - the code is C#, but it doesn't really matter - the fundamental problem is the same one.

Like I said above, though this is all important relevant, info so [edit] your question to include this relevant info such as error messages etc, and remove anything not directly relevant. The comments are just for brief discussion, not for the key components of your problem description. See also [ask]

@ADyson Yes I know we can do this way. But we want to rename with id number and once it renamed and store into destination Just want to rename into source folder also because in a day we will get 1k of images into that folder and hard to find which got uploaded without rename.

@ADyson Ok I'll Update again and repost Thank You

But we want to rename with id number and once it renamed and store into destination Just want to rename into source folder also because in a day we will get 1k of images into that folder and hard to find which got uploaded without rename...I don't dispute that you should rename the files, that sounds fine. But I just don't understand why you make the user physically upload the file contents through the HTML form, if the server already has access to those files in the source folder. That is just a pointless data transfer. The user should just specify which filenames need to be processed.
